# O operando de um operador 'delete' precisa ser opcional

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Eu montei um servidor node, e quando fui fazer os testes para poder subir para produção vi que o eslint estava me acusando um erro:

[image: Erro expresso no Eslint]

Só para constar, está funcionando como devido, o delete está removendo a propriedade do objeto, porém, eu não consigo ser aprovado no teste do eslint e em outros, como do próprio github por conta desse erro. Queria saber qual seria a melhor prática, para o uso do delete nesse caso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simples, porque se você remove a propriedade de uma interface que não é opcional, como o erro consta, o **user** interface já não seria um **user** interface porque o lint entende que você precisaria daquela propriedade para a interface *funcionar*.
O modo mais fácil de resolver é marcando a propriedade como opcional na interface:

```
interface User {
  password?: string;
}
```

Desse modo o lint entende que a interface pode, ou não precisa, conter o password pra que *funcione*, mas sem dizer que a propriedade pode ser passado `null`, veja mais sobre [propriedades opcionais](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties).